# Pass parameter to laravel voyager menu builder link() method

Tags: php, laravel, routes, localization, voyager

I made a navbar using voyager's menu builder. I'm trying to add localization functionality to my app but can't figure out how to pass a `{lang}` parameter to this line of code:

```
@foreach ($items as $menu_item)
    <a href='{{ $menu_item->link() }}' class="nav-link">
@endforeach
```

Normally I would do this:

```
<a href='{{ route('shopIndex', App::getLocale()) }}' class="nav-link">Shop</a>
```

I tried doing this which didn't work:

```
@foreach ($items as $menu_item)
    <a href='{{ route($menu_item->link(), App::getLocale()) }}' class="nav-link">
@endforeach
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the `link()` method give you the name of the route or does it return a **URL**?

Comment: it returns a url

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED: running `dd($menu_item)` gave me these attributes:

```
  #attributes: array:13 [▼
"id" => 18
"menu_id" => 2
"title" => "Shop"
"url" => ""
"target" => "_self"
"icon_class" => null
"color" => "#000000"
"parent_id" => null
"order" => 1
"created_at" => "2023-02-12 07:31:09"
"updated_at" => "2023-02-13 07:45:46"
"route" => "shopIndex"
"parameters" => null
]
```

`$menu_item->route` gives the route name which I can put in a route helper and pass the parameters I want.

Note: some links don't have a route name so you need to define a conditional in case of the links without a route name.

```
<a href='{{ route($menu_item->route ? $menu_item->route : 'cartIndex', App::getLocale()) }}' class="nav-link">
```

Answer (score 1):

`route()` method is used only if you have named routes. If `link()` only returns a **URL**, you should not use it with the `route()` method.
I see one that you want added by current language, like `http://yoursite/en`. Here are two methods you can follow to solve your problem:

1. Create **middleware** and redirect according to current language. Use middleware by grouping your routes.
2. Revise `$menu_item->link()` to give you the route name and use the `route()` method.